# How can I use Fragments to open items on a Drawerlayout, when i used the Activity Drawer Navigation Template that provides android studio?

Tags: android, fragment, material-design

**Template that provide Android Studio**

[image: Template]

This is how I try to do. What is the R.id.x?. I tried using layout id in xml ActivityMain but not the fragment is displayed or overlaid with out activity information.

[image: Add fragment]

After selecting one of the items, the fragment will be displayed above the activity. The activity has several elements belonging to material design as the FAB or the Toolbar, Could this create problems with what I do?

[image: Navigation Drawer]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the end solved the problem using some of the recommendations made in the answers they provided me.

1. Change content_main.xml content. Using a FrameLayout with its correspodiente id.

[image: content_main.xml]

2. Add fragment on onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item)

[image: Add fragment]

3. Result

When I press a menu item ...

[image: Menu]

...the fragment is displayed

[image: Fragment]

Answer (score 2):

In `activity_main.xml` try replacing:

```
<include
    layout="@layout/app_bar_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
```

With this:

```
<FrameLayout android:id="@+id/fragment_container"
             android:layout_width="match_parent"
             android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

And then use `R.id.fragment_container` as your `R.id.x`.

This will however replace the view with the FAB and coordinator layout. But you will probably want to add them to the fragments where you want them.

If not you could try replacing the xml found below in `app_bar_main.xml`, <s>or wrap it in the `FrameLayout`.</s>

```
<include layout="@layout/content_main"/>
```

**Update:**

Replacing in `activity_main.xml` will cause some issues as that removes the toolbar.

If you replace the include in `app_bar_main.xml` your fragments will most likely get overlapped by the toolbar at the top. To prevent this you could try adding `app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"` in the `FrameLayout` snippet above.

Answer (score 1):

R.id.x is the id of the View that your fragment going to be replaced. So in your layout R.layout.xyz you have created a layout

```
<FrameLayout android:id="@+id/fragment_container"
             android:layout_width="match_parent"
             android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

and add/replace the fragment to that id. (R.id.fragment_container) such that your new fragment will be placed in that layout.

```
transaction.add(R.id.fragment_container, firstFragment)
```